# Why does P-Integrability imply Q-Integrability for function and mapping Q

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $f : Ω → R_+$  be a measurable function satisfying

$\int_\Omega f(ω)P(dω) = 1$

Define a mapping by
$Q: A → R_+ $
$Q(A) = \int_\Omega 1_A (ω)f(ω)P(dω)$

1) Let $h: Ω → R_+$ be a non-negative, measurable function. Show that if
h(·)f(·) is P-integrable, then h is Q-integrable.

2) Let h: Ω → R be a measurable function. Show by using part (1) that if
h(·)f(·) is P-integrable then h is Q-integrable and satisfies

$\int_\Omega f(ω)Q(dω)=\int_\Omega h(ω)f(ω)P(dω)$

---

My thoughts:

Let $h_n(x)$ be simple function of the form $\sum_{i=1} 1_{A_i}a_k $ Then:

$\int\sum_{i=1}  a_k1_{A_i}(w)f(w)P(dω) < \infty$ since $h()f()$ is P-integrable

so $\int\sum_{i=1}  a_k1_{A_i}(w)f(w)P(dω) = \sum_{i=1}\int  a_kQ(A_i)$ since the $A_i$ are disjoint and simple. Hence h is Q integrable. The general case is then attained by taking limits and using the Monotone Convergence Theorem.

I'm not sure if this is the correct procedure and I'm not sure how to approach part 2. Any help or advice would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you use Radon-Nikodym Theorem?